ubuntu20, 22 - how to apply ssh custom password prompt
currently, password_prompt is applied like below in /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
[prompting/password]
password_prompt = PASSWORD :
but when I try ssh login, the host asks me
password:
Ubuntu20, 22 are all same.
I've restarted sssd after changing  'password_prompt' in sssd.conf but it's not applied. What do I have to check to apply custom password prompt correctly?
version info:
u20: VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa) / openssh 8.2
u22: VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)" / openssh 8.9
regarding /etc/pam.d/sshd of u20, 22, Here it is.
account    required     pam_nologin.so<br>
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close<br>
session    required     pam_loginuid.so<br>
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke<br>
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic<br>
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate<br>
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]<br>
session    required     pam_limits.so<br>
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]<br>
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale<br>
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open<br>


I've deleted  EOL  version and added version info for u20 and u22.

SSH and SSSD are different packages that do different things. Editing config for SSSD will not affect SSH login. I'm not aware you can change the SSH password prompt without recompiling.
